# Keyboard shortcuts don't work for .cpp files

Tags: sublimetext3

For some reason keyboard shortcuts that work for `.h` files do not work for `.cpp` files. How can I fix this?

Comment: First you need to tell which IDE you are speaking about.

Comment: I thought it was obvious from the flag? SublimeText 3.

Comment: Have you named the file?

Answer (score 0):

This weird problem went away after I [reverted SublimeText to a Freshly Installed State](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html).

On my Ubuntu box that meant making a backup of my configuration file with `tar czf st3.tar ~/.config/sublime-text-3` and then removing it `rm st3.tar ~/.config/sublime-text-3`